# Apple ID replaced with someone else's after iOS 6 upgrade (Security breach)

Tags: upgrade, ios, apple-id

I just updated my iPad retina (3rd generation) with iOS 6 and now my Apple ID has been replaced with someone else's ID.

[image: iTunes Settings]

And its not jailbroken either. How did someone manage to do that? This is a serious security breach, I think.

I logged out of that Apple ID but how can I be sure that they are not tracking anything and won't be able to purchase through my account?

Comment: Did you perform an over the air upgrade? A wipe and restore from an iCloud backup or was your upgrade accomplished via iTunes or Xcode where there could be local backups on the computer?

Comment: @bmike Yes it was an OTA upgrade. Why did you modify the question & screenshot to hide the email of that person, which might help someone in the same situation who come here searching?

Comment: If it's your email address you are posting - feel free to roll back my edits. Even if you are sure someone has hacked your equipment, this isn't the best forum for that sort of post. It was flagged and I decided the best course of action was to edit it. You are free to re-edit and I'll leave it alone, but it's far more likely to get closed/deleted if someone else's personal email is being listed.

Comment: *Re-added this comment here. Where I meant to reply- 
I had this happen to me when I got a refurbished one due to a swapped out for another one. Even though I updated the phone and pulled a backup up it had the old A.ID for someone else. I think it was because this setting may have been saved before I change them to my details. And the old association stays with the phone for some reason. I cannot remember the full details. But if it was not a brand new device when you got it then I do not think someone has hacked your device – markhunte 22 hours ago

Comment: Makes sense but mine was a brand new one.

Answer (score 1):

This is not as serious as it appears as signing into a device using a different Apple ID does not give one access to all the data on your device. What happens when you launch an app that you have officially purchased from the App Store? If it asks for the password of your proper Apple ID, then I would skip to the end of this answer and call Apple because that means the rogue account is actually signed in. If, however, it launches, then you are in fact logged into your proper account.

First, sign out of that Apple ID. Then sign into your existing (proper) one. Once done, sign out and then proceed to change the password on your Apple ID: https://appleid.apple.com/ as a proactive measure. And I would strongly advise you to use Apple's two-step verification if it is available in your country.

There exists no known way to hack into an OTA firmware update and hijack a system. iOS is actually quite secure. While I can explain how that email got there, I can say that it's likely an Apple server side error. Or someone local got a hold of your device and is messing with you.

Lastly, if you are 100% sure it occurred without explanation, I would contact Apple and not send emails to the iTunes Team, as they falls outside the scope of anything they can help you with. International contact info can be found here: http://support.apple.com/kb/he57

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest deactivating your iTunes account ASAP. You should get in touch with Apple support too.

Comment: I tried contacting their support but they seem unhelpful, telling me instructions of having trouble signing in with my apple id.